# Jquery ui slider change automatically on manual input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

This is the code for my jquery ui slider:

```
var slidervalue = 100;  
$(function () {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 100,
min: 1,
max: 700,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val(ui.value );

slidervalue = ui.value;
}
});


$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

});
```

And this is a extra the function i have created to fetch a number from my deal title and calculate savings and display the result.

```
 function updateSlider() {

        $.each($('.coupontitle'),function(index,coupObj){

                if ($(coupObj).text().match(/(\d+)\%/i))
                {
                  var percent = $(coupObj).text().match(/(\d+)\%/i);

                  var savings = ((percent[1]*.01) * slidervalue).toFixed(0);

                  $('span',coupObj).html('Save: $'+savings);
                }
                else if ($(coupObj).text().match(/\$(\d+)/i))
                {
                    var percent = $(coupObj).text().match(/\$(\d+)/i);
                    var savings = ((percent[1]*.01) * 100).toFixed(0);               
                    $('span',coupObj).html('Save: $'+savings);      
                }

              });
    }
```

this code is working properly along with the slider. right now, when a user slides the slider the amount corresponding to the slider is passed using ui.value and is passed to the above function and is calculated.

But, when i input a value into the text box manually, i want the slider to move automatically, and i want that value to pass into the function to calculate. Right now, when a amount is entered manually, the input value is not passed into the function.

I want the slider to work as this site: http://www.chippmunk.com/

I came across this jsfiddle, which does the work, but when manually entered it is not passing the text box value into my function to carry on with the calculation.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MD3mX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, I would move the $-sign out of the input though.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/MD3mX/847/

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 1000,
    min: 0,
    max: 5000000,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("input").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("input").change(function () {
    $("#slider").slider("value",this.value);
});
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/KLj6Z/

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("input").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$("input").on("keyup",function(e){
     $("#slider").slider("value",this.value);
});
```

Comment: thanks rusln, but on providing the input, only the slider is moving proportionately, but the value is not getting passed. i want the value to be passed when a user inputs it into the box manually similar to the site www.chippmunk.com

Comment: by moving the slider's handle, the value of the slider appears in the input field, by entering a value in the input field the slider's handle moves to a position according to the value entered in the input field. Now, what do you mean by the value being passed and where should it be passed ?

Comment: Oh i get it, you want to listen to changes on the input field so that the slider reacts immediately, without the need to press enter first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was talking about this change only. "keyup" function did the work.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer above is very useful and it works fine for single value sliders. But someone like me might wonder how to control two values in [Range Slider](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/range.html).
So, if we use range slider, we need to pass an array as **values** and for range slider we can handle it like this

```
var min_val = 0;
var max_val = 1000;

function minMaxControl(type) {
  if (type == 'min') {
    min_val = $('#min').val();
  } else if (type == 'max') {
    max_val = $('#max').val();
  }
  $("#slider-range").slider('values', [min_val, max_val]);
}

$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  values: [min_val, max_val],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#min").val(ui.values[0]);
    $("#max").val(ui.values[1]);

  }
});
```

You can see the full code and demo here. https://jsfiddle.net/N4K1B/2tv9phke/1/

So basically in above answer the single parameter of the slider was controlled like this:

```
$("#slider").slider("value",this.value);
```

And for range slider instead of passing a single value we are passing an array of two values like this:

```
$("#slider-range").slider('values', [min_val, max_val]);
```

Hope this answer may help someone if someone is still using jquery-ui slider.
For more, please refer to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range)